# App crashes when trying to access a viewcontroller from AppDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, storyboard

This is how I am trying to get my PlayersViewController:

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [tabBarController viewControllers][0];
PlayersViewController *playersViewController = [navigationController viewControllers][0];
```

The app crashes after the 3rd line with the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController viewControllers]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x715b290'
```

I am new to IOS programming so I can't figure out what the problem is. I am not getting my PlayersViewController correct ? Here is the image with my storyboard.

[image]

Comment: Navigation Controller doesn't have the views added to it yet by the looks of it.

Comment: @FaddishWorm: And how can I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UINavigationController` that contains the `PlayersViewController` controller is at index 1 in the tab bar controller's `viewControllers` array. The indexing is from left to right, that is, the leftmost tab has index 0. The "Players" tab is to the right of the "Gestures", and the tab bar has two items, so therefore the view controller associated with that tab index is at index 1.

The message you are seeing is because at index 0 there is a `UIViewController` instance corresponding with the label "View Controller - Gestures" in your storyboard, and you are trying to send it a message that `UIViewController` does not respond to, in the belief that it is a `UINavigationController`.